# $f\geq 0$ and $\overline{\int_a^b}f=0$ on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Tags: real-analysis

> $f\geq 0$ and $\overline{\int_a^b}f=0$ on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is Riemann integrable. This statement is true or false? Argument.

I am 99% this statement is false. However I am not sure how to give a formal argument. Previously, I proved that if $f$ is continuos, non negative and $\int_a^b f=0$ on $[a,b]$ then $f(x)=0, \forall x\in[a,b]$.

Could be necessary a counter-example? I am studying the Riemann integral from Darboux's perspective.

$\overline{\int_a^b}f$ is defined as $\inf\{U(P,f): P\in P[a,b]\}$

Could I say, this function does not ensure continuity or we can't deduce from the hypothesis that $\underline{\int_a^b}f=0$, then is not Riemann integrable?

Comment: If $f\ge0$, what is the smallest that $\underline{\int_a^b}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ could be?

Comment: @robjohn 0, of course. But it does not imply the lower integral is 0.

Comment: Can the lower integral  be greater than the upper integral?

Comment: Thank you so much, @robjohn!

Comment: I just asked a couple of questions ;-)